# How to roll my own Jagged Foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

My application frequently iterates over jagged arrays.  Rather than explicit nested loops all over the place, I'm trying to implement foreach like functionality where I can pass a lambda.

My latest attempt looks is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JaggedTest
{
    static class Global
    {
        // Does not work
        public static void ForEachJagged<T>(Array A, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Action<T>> F)
        {
            foreach (var Item in A)
            {
                if (Item is Array)
                {
                    ForEachJagged<T>((Array)Item, F);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression Invo =
                        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Invoke(F,
                        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(Item));
                    Console.WriteLine(Invo.ToString());
                    // How to execute "Invo" ?
                }
            }
        }
    }

        class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] Foo = new int[3][] {
                  new int[] {1}
                 ,new int[] {2,3,4,5,6}
                 ,new int[] {7,8,9}
                };

            Global.ForEachJagged<int>(Foo, X => Console.Write(X.ToString() + " "));

        }
    }
}
```

This program produces the expected "ToString" debug output for the lambda expression, but I'm stuck trying to actually execute this expression.  What is the proper way to execute a lambda expression passed as a function parameter?

-- EDIT --

Working jagged foreach based on Slava Utesinov's feedback:

```
public static void ForEachJagged<T>(Array A, Action<T> F)
{
   foreach (var Item in A)
   {
      if (Item is Array)
      {
          ForEachJagged<T>((Array)Item, F);
      }
      else
      {
         F((T)Item);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Expression<Action<T>>`. Why not accept an `Action<T>`? Using an expression tree is normally only required if you want to "transport" the lambda to some other layer like when you want a LINQ `Select` in C# to be executed as a SQL `SELECT` at the database.

Comment: @Martin, no purpose.  I'm new to C# and got derailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `Compile` method:

```
foreach (var Item in A)
{
    if (Item is Array)  
        ForEachJagged<T>((Array)Item, F);   
    else    
        F.Compile()((T)Item);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Slava.  This works, but in my real application, JaggedForEach is far too slow compared to nested loops.  I suppose this slowness is due to Compile(), but I am unsure.

Comment: Instead of `Expression<Action<T>>` type just use `Action<T>`, so you will need to call `F((T)Item)` without `Compile`

Answer (score 1):

If you're really hung up on it being just one `foreach` loop, you can do something like the following:

```
foreach (var item in arr.SelectMany(a => a))
{
    Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
}
```

But really, I would just recommend that you do the nesting. All the effort spent trying to get the code to look pretty is going to A) make the code only look prettier to *you*, B) make the code run appreciably if not significantly slower, or C) both.

If it's the indentation that hangs you up, you can always make it look like this:

```
foreach (var nest in arr)
foreach (var item in nest)
{
    Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
}
```